# pandas creating a new column based on other other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called bank and ı would like to create a new column explaining percentage change but when I try ı encounter with this error:unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
How can I solve this problem or is there other ways for me to create this column?

```
bank=bank.iloc[0:15,0:4]
pctchange=(bank['Yüksek']-bank['Düşük'])-bank['Düşük']
def risk(bank):
    if pctchange>0.3:
        val='High Risk'
    elif pctchange>0.2 :
        val='Middle Risk'
    else:
        val='Low Risk'
    return val
bank.apply(risk,axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you please share an example of your dataset? Maybe you should first create a separate column name percentage and then apply risk function to that.

Comment: https://tr.investing.com/equities/eregli-demir-celik-historical-data This is the website I got the data from. It is an equity prices data. You should click 'Verileri İndir' to download it.

Comment: Hi @blknt3191 - welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the posts on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a great question. Specifically, [posting links to datasets is discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251236/3888719) - instead, work on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show us (in code or pasted into the question) what your data looks like and try to help us re-create the problem. Good luck!

Comment: In your case, the problem is probably occurring because your data is encoded as strings rather than numeric types. See [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). This can happen in lots of ways, but especially when reading in text (e.g. csv) data if there are a mix of numbers and characters in the dataset. See the na_values and dtypes arguments to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: when I write "pd.to_numeric(bank)" now I encounter: TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series. I am about to cry.

Comment: Try this: `bank = bank.astype('float64')`

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4,20'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sanitize your data and then try to change type, like this:

```py
# Replace commas with points
bank = bank.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))

# Convert to float
bank = bank.astype('float64')
```

Comment: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). It says this.

Comment: This error message signals a different and unrelated problem: you can't do if/elif statements with dataframes/Series (pctchange) the way you do it in your code.

Comment: How should I do can you fix it?

Comment: See my answer to your new question. If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you wish, you can also add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle. In any case, have a nice day.